# I wonder Collections.sort with super bounded wild card

Tags: java

The lecture said that the structure of the sort algorithm is as follows.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T> void sort<List<T> list
```

and if there is no wild card in the sort, an error will occur in the next code.

```
class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
     private int id;
     public Car(int id) { this.id = id; }

     @Override
     public int compareTo(Car obj) {
     return this.id - obj.id;
}
class ECar extends Car {
     public ECar(int id) {
         super(id);
     }
}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ECar> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new ECar(1200));
        list.add(new ECar(1300));
        Collections.sort(list); // it will error
    }
}
```

The reason is ECar class doesn't implements `Comparable<ECar>`

I have question that point. Although sort implemented with `<? super T>`, it is not mean that implements `Comparable<ECar>`.

wild card with under bounded make simply T can accept Car and ECar Object. But how come the above problem is solved?